# JavaScript IF statement Operators not matching (x == 1 && y == 'Parameter')

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

I have been banging my head on this for a few days and am probably just blind to the issue at this point.

I am setting parameters and passing them into a function and want to make my next step by matching parameters within a series of IF/Else IF statements. Here is an example:

```
function Test(type, time) {
  this.state = {
    type: 1,
    time: '1H'
  }
  this.render()
}

Test.prototype.setState = function(newState) {
  for (var key in newState) {
    this.state[key] = newState[key]
  }
  var timeee = JSON.stringify(this.state.type);
  var typeee = JSON.stringify(this.state.time);

  document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = timeee;
  document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = typeee;

  this.render()
}

Test.prototype.render = function() {
  var type = this.state.type;
  var time = JSON.stringify(this.state.time);

  testDay(type, time);
}

function testDay(type, time) {
  console.log(">>>>> TYPE IS: " + type + " " + "TIME IS: " + time + " <<<<<")
  if(type == 1 && time == '1H'){
     console.log("-1-24-");
     } 
  else if(type == 2){
       console.log("-2-");
     }
  else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
  }
};

var myTest = new Test()
```

Somehow, when I add the second parameter of 'time' it breaks the whole thing. If you have any thoughts or experience with this I'd really appreciate it since I am going a bit mad. My end goal is something like this:

```
  if(type == 1 && time == '1M'){ 
     //call specific function
     } 
  else if(type == 1 && time == '1H'){ 
     //call specific function
     }
  else if(type == 1 && time == '1D'){ 
     //call specific function
     }
  else if(type == 2 && time == '1M'){ 
     //call specific function
     }
  else if(type == 2 && time == '1H'){ 
     //call specific function
     }
  else if(type == 2 && time == '1D'){ 
     //call specific function
     }
  else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
  }
```

Here is an example of it that you can tinker with:

http://jsbin.com/semevi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: In your example time is `"1H"`, including the quotes. Why do you pass it through `JSON.stringify()` first? That's what's breaking it.

Comment: _“It breaks the whole thing”_ is not a helpful problem description. What is your expected result (and how do you test whether it’s correct) and what is actually happening (and how do you see that it is happening)?

Comment: There is no reason this shouldn't work, provided `time` is **actually** '1M'.

Comment: Oh...thanks @Juhana, let me look at that!

Comment: @Idos - that's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure if I was just wrong about that, thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From debugging it looks like your `time` variable has an extra set of quotes around it, so it will not match `'1M'`. Simply remove that extra set of quotes. also use a debugger to track down these issues

Change:

`var time = JSON.stringify(this.state.time);`

to:

`var time = this.state.time;`

Additionally, I would suggest you change that set of if statement to nested ones for readability and just overall better coding style:

```
if (type === 1) {
    if (time === '1M') {
        //call specific function
    } else if (time === '1H') {
        //call specific function
    } else if (time === '1D') {
        //call specific function
    } else {
        console.log("NO MATCH");
    }
} else if (type === 2) {
    if (time === '1M') {
        //call specific function
    } else if (time === '1H') {
        //call specific function
    } else if (time === '1D') {
        //call specific function
    } else {
        console.log("NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

Also notice the use of `===` instead of `==` for faster and more strict matching.

Comment: Do you recommend any debugger in particular? I haven't been using one up to this point, which I infer is pretty obvious.

Comment: you can just use the chrome console to debug

Answer (score -1):

```
     if(type == 1 && time == '"1M"'){ //use this to override
 console.log("1, 1M"); 
 } 
     else if(type == 2){ //matching just the first parameter works
   console.log("1, 1H"); 
 }
     else {
console.log("NO MATCH");
```

}

fixed it..problem of quotes

Comment: This makes it work but it would be much better to fix it so that the quotes aren't added there in the first place. You also don't need to escape double quotes inside single quotes.